# Cannot access a closed stream Exception

Tags: c#, stream, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, memorystream

I'm trying to "copy" an image from another image, reduce it's height and width, and return it as stream to retrieve in another class and show as an Image. But when I get the stream in the other class, and exception is thrown; "cannot access to closed stream".

This method gets the image path, reduces its size and returns as a stream.

```
public Stream getImagenCopia (string dataImagen)
    {
        Bitmap ImageOrig = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (dataImagen);
        var ImagenCopia = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (ImageOrig, 80, 80, false);


        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ())
        {
            ImagenCopia.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 40, ms);

            return ms;
        }
    }
```

This method receives the stream and sets it in Image source

```
var cim = auxFotos.getImagenCopia(path);
setImagen(img, cim);

void setImagen (Image img, Stream strm)
    {
        img.Source = ImageSource.FromStream (() =>
        {
            return strm;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're disposing of the `MemoryStream` because you're using a `using` block. By the time you try to use the return value later in your code, it's unavailable.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream ())
{
    ImagenCopia.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 40, ms);

    return ms;
}
```

Remove the `using` statement:

```
Bitmap ImageOrig = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(dataImagen);
var ImagenCopia = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(ImageOrig, 80, 80, false);

var ms = new MemoryStream());
ImagenCopia.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 40, ms);
return ms;
```

If you see memory consumption spike because resources aren't being garbage collected, you may have to clean it up manually after you're done using it, perhaps by calling `.Dispose()` on it.

Comment: Thank you Grant!! Another question, `var ImagenCopia = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(ImageOrig,80,80,false);` is right? I don't think it is working because the Image doesn't appear in img.Source and I get not error messages or anything :(

Comment: Ok, I'll do it! Thank you again! :)